# Average Age from DOB Field - MySQL / PHP

Tags: mysql, average, date

I wasn't sure how I could calculate the average age of my contacts who all exist in a mysql table with a DOB date field such as YYYY-MM-DD.

Is there a way to do with with a MySQL call (please note I am using cakephp but that shouldn't be an issue)

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can determine age by using [`DATEDIFF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff):

```
DATEDIFF(TO_DAYS(NOW()), TO_DAYS(DOB))
```

The average is found in MySQL using [`AVG()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg):

```
AVG(Column)
```

So combine those:

```
SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(TO_DAYS(NOW()), TO_DAYS(DOB))) as `Average` FROM Contacts;
```

Note that this returns the average age in days, not years. To obtain years you can average the years part of each date:

```
SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(YEAR(NOW()), YEAR(DOB))) as `Average` FROM Contacts;
```

Or as @TimDearborn suggested, divide the day average by 365.242199.

Comment: If you want the answer in years, divide by 365.242199  `SELECT AVG((TO_DAYS(NOW())-TO_DAYS(DOB)))/365.242199  from table;`

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer

```
SELECT AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, DOB, CURDATE())) AS `Average` FROM Contacts WHERE DOB IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to do a datediff if you're using Bailey Parker's second method.  Just subtract the years and take the avg.

```
SELECT AVG(YEAR(NOW())-YEAR(dob)) as `Average` FROM users;
```